# jQuery UI Drag and Drop mouse position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm developing a site where you can move different "modules" (squares with information) from one place to another in the page with jQuery UI.

My problem is that when I drag one module to a droppable zone, the place recognized by the script is the middle of the module and not the mouse position.

I don't know if it is posible to have a workaround this, but I could figure out yet.

I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicosunshine/vMpNA/3/ that shows the problem.

Thank you in advance!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the tolerance of the droppable to pointer, ie

```
jQuery("#dropHere").droppable({
 drop: function(){
        console.log("dropped!");
    },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).addClass("over");
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("over");
    },
    tolerance: 'pointer'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vMpNA/4/

[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#option-tolerance)

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't know how I missed that!